# Trying to Compute the differences in two different ArrayLists of Objects with Instance Fields of Type Integer[JAVA]

Tags: java, object, oop, arraylist

```
package pckg;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Tester 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        ArrayList<TesterObj> my_first_objects = new ArrayList<TesterObj>();
        TesterObj one = new TesterObj(5,"john",6.8,"HELKEOLOSSJK NHSSB BSBSJBS NS S");
        TesterObj two = new TesterObj(25,"eric",12.32,"SKSMK skm1d dms dnms kmdks");
        TesterObj three = new TesterObj(15,"sally",2.40,"dskmdnk kmdk kwmd kdsmkd qpdok");
        TesterObj four = new TesterObj(31,"susan",9.87,"ksmdks qwersc kpaolxnio akmdn");
        TesterObj five = new TesterObj(18,"mary",86.32,"dksnd oqoijdl padxl");

        my_first_objects.add(one);
        my_first_objects.add(two);
        my_first_objects.add(three);
        my_first_objects.add(four);
        my_first_objects.add(five);

        ArrayList<TesterObj> my_second_objects = new ArrayList<TesterObj>();

        TesterObj six = new TesterObj(12,"jolly",20.4,"dxksmd oasodkx skldm");
        TesterObj seven = new TesterObj(93,"buddy",34.32,"osdk lsldm lasdkoa");
        TesterObj eight = new TesterObj(44,"kurt",90.54,"dksmd llamz kmska alsmx");
        TesterObj nine = new TesterObj(35,"jimi",923.23,"alsmx zmasx skdm akdm");
        TesterObj ten = new TesterObj(42,"kanye",12.43,"aposdkx xksmd");

        my_second_objects.add(six);
        my_second_objects.add(seven);
        my_second_objects.add(eight);
        my_second_objects.add(nine);
        my_second_objects.add(ten);

        match(my_first_objects, my_second_objects);
    }

    // OBJS_ONE and OBJS_TWO MUST BE EQUAL IN SIZE!!! , 3 is number of instance fields to compare

    public static HashMap<TesterObj,TesterObj> match(ArrayList<TesterObj> objs_one, ArrayList<TesterObj> objs_two)
    {
        ArrayList<Integer> diffs = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        HashMap<TesterObj,TesterObj> map = new HashMap<TesterObj,TesterObj>();

        for(int z=0;z<objs_one.size(); z++) 
        {
            for(int l = 0;l<objs_two.size(); l++) 
            {
                System.out.println("THE AGE OF OBJ ONE IS " + objs_one.get(z).age +
                        "THE AGE OF OBJ TWO IS " + objs_two.get(l).age );
                diffs.add(Math.abs(objs_one.get(z).age - objs_one.get(l).age));
                System.out.println(diffs);
            }
        }
        return map;
    }
}
```

The first iteration(of the inner loop) should return 7 because `Math.abs(5-12)` is 7 but it instead returns 0. This pattern continues and the next iteration returns 10 when it should return `Math.abs(5-93)` or 88.

The goal of this project is then to continue this on a row by row basis (each obj one iterates once for n obj two elements) until finished then the lowest difference is returned.

Answer (score 0):

Change
Math.abs(objs_one.get(z).age - objs_one.get(l).age
to
Math.abs(objs_one.get(z).age - objs_two.get(l).age